# How can I show components of something transform as a (0,2) tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors, index-notation

Suppose that $B_i$ are the components of a covariant vector. Show that $\frac{\partial B_j}{\partial x^k} - \frac{\partial B_k}{\partial x^j}$ are the components of a (0,2) tensor.

I know that the components of a (0,2) tensor transform like this:

$\frac{\partial \bar{B_j}}{\partial \bar{x^k}} -\frac{\partial \bar{B_k}}{\partial \bar{x^j}}  = \sum_{\alpha,\beta=1}^n \left ( \frac{\partial B_{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}} - \frac{\partial B_{\beta}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right)\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial \bar{x}^j} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial \bar{x}^k}$

So $$\bar{B}_j = \sum_{\alpha=1}^n B_{\alpha} \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial\bar{x}^j}$$

and $$\bar{B}_k = \sum_{\beta=1}^n B_{\beta} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial\bar{x}^k}$$

Can someone please help me solve this question? I am preparing for my exam and my professor said this question is important to know and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in the half way. The next step is just differentiate $\bar{B}_j =  B_{\alpha} \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial\bar{x}^j}$ and $\bar{B}_k = B_{\beta} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial\bar{x}^k}$ as

$$\frac{\partial\bar{B}_j}{\partial \bar{x}^k } = \frac{\partial B_{\alpha}}{\partial \bar{x}^k } \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial\bar{x}^j}+B_{\alpha} \frac{\partial^2 x^{\alpha}}{\partial\bar{x}^k\partial\bar{x}^j} = \frac{\partial B_{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\gamma}} \frac{\partial x^{\gamma}}{\partial\bar{x}^k} \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial\bar{x}^j}+B_{\alpha} \frac{\partial^2 x^{\alpha}}{\partial\bar{x}^k\partial\bar{x}^j}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial\bar{B}_k}{\partial \bar{x}^j } = \frac{\partial B_{\beta}}{\partial \bar{x}^j } \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial\bar{x}^k}+B_{\beta} \frac{\partial^2 x^{\beta}}{\partial\bar{x}^j\partial\bar{x}^k} = \frac{\partial B_{\beta}}{\partial x^{\gamma}} \frac{\partial x^{\gamma}}{\partial\bar{x}^j} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial\bar{x}^k}+B_{\beta} \frac{\partial^2 x^{\beta}}{\partial\bar{x}^j\partial\bar{x}^k}$$

changing dummy indices from first equation $\gamma \rightarrow \beta$ (for the first term) and the second equation $\gamma \rightarrow \alpha$ (for the first term) and $\beta \rightarrow \alpha$ (for the second term) and substract them, you'll have the desired result. Note that the last terms cancel each other because we always assume the transformation is smooth so that the mixed partial derivatives is commute.

Comment: After doing the subtraction I have this result:
$$
\Large \Bigg(\frac{\partial B_{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}} - \frac{\partial B_{\beta}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\Bigg)\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\prime j}}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x^{\prime k}}
$$
So why does this show the desired result? @Sou

Comment: @MRT This this trasformation rule for your question (b) which is indeed tensor. But the transformation for (a) like one of the equation in my answer above is imply that vector in (a) is not a tensor.

Comment: Ahh so $\Large \frac{\partial B^{\prime}_j}{\partial x^{\prime k}}$ is not a tensor. This is what I don't understand. I don't know why the first equation is not a tensor. @Sou

Comment: @MRT there is an additional term in the RHS. If it is always zero then we have transformation rule for tensot order (0,2). But this isnt the case.

Comment: So because the additional term doesn't get cancelled like in the original answer, this makes it not tensor. I don't know why it's not always zero? Is it because of a smooth function? @Sou

Comment: @MRT You just have to find a counterexample. Consider transformation $(r,\theta) \to (x,y)=(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ that is the usual trans.from polar coordinates. The second mixed partial derivatives $\partial_r \partial_{\theta} x$ does not always vanish so there you go.