# Examples of Tensor Transformation Law

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, tensors, general-relativity, index-notation

> Let $T_{\mu\nu}$ be a rank $(0,2)$ tensor, $V^\mu$ a vector, and $U_\mu$ a covector. Using the definition of tensors based on the tensor transformation law, determine whether each of the following is a tensor. If it is, state its rank.
>   $$
> (a)\,\,A_{\mu\nu} \equiv \frac{\partial U_\mu}{\partial x^\nu},\quad(b)\,\,F_{\mu\nu} \equiv A_{[\mu\nu]},\text{where $A_{\mu\nu}$ is defined in (a)}
> $$

I have the tensor transformation law as:
$$
T^{\prime i_1i_2\cdots i_p}_{\quad\quad\quad j_1j_2\cdots j_q} = \frac{\partial X^{\prime i_1}}{\partial X^{k_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial X^{\prime i_p}}{\partial X^{k_p}}\frac{\partial X^{m_1}}{\partial X^{\prime j_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial X^{m_q}}{\partial X^{\prime j_q}}T^{k_1k_2\cdots k_p}_{\quad\quad\quad m_1m_2\cdots m_q}
$$

I am not sure how this would even look for a rank $(0,2)$ tensor. Would it be:
$$
T^{\prime}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial X^{m_1}}{\partial X^{\prime \mu}}\frac{\partial X^{m_2}}{\partial X^{\prime \nu}}T^{}_{m_1m_2}
$$

I don't see how this would be useful in showing $(a)$ is a tensor.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor? Substitute the transformation law for $U$, and use the Leibniz rule to see that there is an unwanted term in the transformation rule of $A$, and thus prove that $A$ is not tensorial. But what about $F$?

Comment: I think that I need to show that $A_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor. And I don't see how to substitute U into the transformation law @Trebor

Comment: Would a substitution give:
$$\Large U^{\prime}_{\mu} = \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\prime \mu}}U_{\nu}$$
But I don't see the use in this either @Trebor

Comment: So I would use the transformation law? giving:
$$\Large A^\prime_{\alpha\beta} = \frac{\partial x^{m_1}}{\partial x^{\prime\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{m_2}}{\partial x^{\prime\beta}}A_{\alpha\beta}$$
But what of the $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: Forgot to tag you before @Sou

Comment: No. You have to show that  $A_{\mu\nu}$ does not transform properly as you wrote above. Hence not a tensor. But $F_{\mu\nu}$ is.

Comment: As I wrote above? Like in the original question? I don't see why this hasn't transformed properly. I'm dreadfully confused @Sou

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438104/how-can-i-show-components-of-something-transform-as-a-0-2-tensor?noredirect=1&lq=1) when you worked out the expression for $\partial_{\nu} U_{\mu}$ you’ll notice that it doesnt transform as your last expression in the question. Hence it is not a tensor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show components of something transform as a (0,2) tensor ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438104/how-can-i-show-components-of-something-transform-as-a-0-2-tensor)

Comment: Oh wait are you saying that because
$$
\Large T^{\prime}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\prime\mu}}\frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{\prime\nu}}T_{\alpha\beta} \neq \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\prime \mu}}U_{\nu} = U^{\prime}_{\nu} = \frac{\partial U_\mu}{\partial x^\nu}
$$
Then $A_{\mu\nu}$ is not a tensor. @Sou